# Linear Integer Programming for solving Sudoku

Tags: mathematical-optimization, puzzle

I have generated sudoku solver using a recursive scheme, however, i wish to find a more mathematica like solution to solving sudoku. I tried using `FindInstance` but to no use.

here is my attempt so far:

```
grid = {{9, 0, 0, 2, 3, 7, 6, 8, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 8, 4, 0, 0, 7, 3}, {8, 0, 7, 
1, 0, 5, 0, 2, 9}, {0, 0, 4, 5, 9, 8, 3, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 6}, {5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7}, {4, 0, 1, 3, 0, 6, 2, 9, 
5}, {0, 5, 0, 9, 1, 0, 7, 3, 8}, {3, 0, 8, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

i deliberately replace 0's for symbols

```
symgrid = grid /. 0 :> Module[{x}, x]
(* {{9, x$8160, x$8161, 2, 3, 7, 6, 8, x$8162}, {x$8163, 2, x$8164, 8, 4,
   x$8165, x$8166, 7, 3}, {8, x$8167, 7, 1, x$8168, 5, x$8169, 2, 
  9}, {x$8170, x$8171, 4, 5, 9, 8, 3, x$8172, x$8173}, {2, x$8174, 
  x$8175, x$8176, x$8177, 1, x$8178, x$8179, 6}, {5, 1, x$8180, 
  x$8181, x$8182, x$8183, x$8184, 4, 7}, {4, x$8185, 1, 3, x$8186, 6, 
  2, 9, 5}, {x$8187, 5, x$8188, 9, 1, x$8189, 7, 3, 8}, {3, x$8190, 8,
   x$8191, 5, x$8192, x$8193, x$8194, x$8195}} *)
```

one can get symbols in the `symgrid` using:

```
symbols = Cases[symgrid, _Symbol, Infinity];
```

i placed four constraints on the system: the sum of all the rows and that of all the columns should be 45 i.e. 1+2+...+9 including the  3x3 `submatrices` that i generate using 'getSubMatrices` with the fourth constraint that the values for the symbols lie in the range 1-9.

```
Clear@getSubMatrices;
getSubMatrices[grid_, x_Symbol] := 
Block[{row, col, submatrix},
{row, col} = First@Position[grid, x];
submatrix = (Plus @@ # == 45) &@
Flatten[Which[row <= 3 && col <= 3, Take[grid, 3, 3],
  row <= 3 && col <= 6, Take[grid, 3, 4 ;; 6], 
  row <= 3 && col <= 9, Take[grid, 3, 7 ;; 9],
  row <= 6 && col <= 3, Take[grid, 4 ;; 6, 3], 
  row <= 6 && col <= 6, Take[grid, 4 ;; 6, 4 ;; 6], 
  row <= 6 && col <= 9, Take[grid, 4 ;; 6, 7 ;; 9],
  row <= 9 && col <= 3, Take[grid, 7 ;; 9, 3], 
  row <= 9 && col <= 6, Take[grid, 7 ;; 9, 4 ;; 6], 
  row <= 9 && col <= 9, Take[grid, 7 ;; 9, 7 ;; 9]]]
]
```

I might be wrong here but i think the constraints should be enough to get the solution to Sudoku. However, using the formulation below I get duplicate values in the row:

```
FindInstance[
And @@ Join[Table[Plus @@ symgrid[[i]] == 45, {i, 9}], 
Table[Plus @@ symgrid[[All, i]] == 45, {i, 9}], 
DeleteDuplicates[getSubMatrices[symgrid, #] & /@ symbols], (1 <= # <= 9) & /@ 
symbols], symbols]

(* {{x$8160 -> 8, x$8161 -> 1, x$8162 -> 1, x$8163 -> 8, x$8164 -> 1, 
x$8165 -> 9, x$8166 -> 3, x$8167 -> 1, x$8168 -> 6, x$8169 -> 6, 
x$8170 -> 1, x$8171 -> 5, x$8172 -> 5, x$8173 -> 5, x$8174 -> 9, 
x$8175 -> 9, x$8176 -> 5, x$8177 -> 7, x$8178 -> 1, x$8179 -> 5, 
x$8180 -> 9, x$8181 -> 8, x$8182 -> 1, x$8183 -> 1, x$8184 -> 9, 
x$8185 -> 6, x$8186 -> 9, x$8187 -> 5, x$8188 -> 5, x$8189 -> 2, 
x$8190 -> 8, x$8191 -> 4, x$8192 -> 6, x$8193 -> 8, x$8194 -> 2, 
x$8195 -> 1}} *)
```

Can you kindly let me know how to use the `FindInstance` properly to get the right solution that i do get recursively (below):

[image]

Comment: Check this: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/974303

Comment: you can use `Unique@x` instead of `Module[{x}, x]`

Comment: @happyfish thanks  for pointing it out !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the system has the tendency to generate results provided that the system is not too undetermined.

for instance if we use the grid (same as above but with slightly fewer unknowns) and using additional constraint i.e. product of elements in rows and columns equals 9! :

```
grid = {{9, 0, 0, 2, 3, 7, 6, 8, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 8, 4, 0, 0, 7, 3}, {8, 
0, 7, 1, 0, 5, 0, 2, 9}, {0, 0, 4, 5, 9, 8, 3, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0, 4,
 0, 1, 0, 0, 6}, {5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 7}, {4, 0, 1, 3, 0, 6, 
2, 9, 5}, {0, 5, 0, 9, 1, 0, 7, 3, 8}, {3, 0, 8, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 
4}};

symgrid = grid /. 0 :> Unique@x;
symbols = Cases[symgrid, _Symbol, Infinity];

Clear@getSubMatrices;
getSubMatrices[grid_, x_Symbol] := Block[{row, col, submatrix},
{row, col} = First@Position[grid, x];
submatrix = (Plus @@ # == 45) &@
Flatten[Which[row <= 3 && col <= 3, Take[grid, 3, 3],
row <= 3 && col <= 6, Take[grid, 3, 4 ;; 6], 
row <= 3 && col <= 9, Take[grid, 3, 7 ;; 9],
row <= 6 && col <= 3, Take[grid, 4 ;; 6, 3], 
row <= 6 && col <= 6, Take[grid, 4 ;; 6, 4 ;; 6], 
row <= 6 && col <= 9, Take[grid, 4 ;; 6, 7 ;; 9],
row <= 9 && col <= 3, Take[grid, 7 ;; 9, 3], 
row <= 9 && col <= 6, Take[grid, 7 ;; 9, 4 ;; 6], 
row <= 9 && col <= 9, Take[grid, 7 ;; 9, 7 ;; 9]]]
] 


sol = FindInstance[
And @@ Join[Table[Plus @@ symgrid[[i]] == 45, {i, 9}], 
Table[Plus @@ symgrid[[All, i]] == 45, {i, 9}], 
Table[Times @@ symgrid[[i]] == 9!, {i, 9}], 
Table[Times @@ symgrid[[All, i]] == 9!, {i, 9}], 
DeleteDuplicates[getSubMatrices[symgrid, #] & /@ symbols]], 
symbols]

sympos = Flatten[Position[symgrid, #] & /@ symbols, 1];

symfilled = First[symgrid /. sol];

rule = Map[# ->Framed[Style[symfilled[[Sequence @@ #]], Bold], 
  RoundingRadius -> 50, Background -> LightGreen ] &, sympos];

ReplacePart[symgrid, Dispatch[rule]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]